# Anyone know how to get rid of space between my main image and image below?

Tags: html, css-position

I think the problem occurred because of my relative positioning of the scroll box, but I am not sure how to fix that, since the scroll box needs to remain in that position, can anyone help me?

Thanks so much!!

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wp76qjga/

HTML Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Java/jquery.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Feline</title>

<body background="../Images/DSC_8592(sm5).jpg">
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="top">
  <h1 style="font-size:60px">L'Auberge De Napoleon III</h1>
      <nav id="mainnav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Index.html" >Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Properties Features.html">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="Activities.html">Activities</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact.html" class="thispage">Contact US</a></li>
          <li><a href="Pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
</header>
    <div id="contactimg">
        <img src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/cmr5496/sky_main.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="scroll" style="position:relative; left:0px; top:-500px; width:350px; height:480px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px;">
        <div style="position:relative; left:65px"><img style="padding-left:px" width="190px" height="180px" src="../Images/Contact Photos/Map5.png"></div>
            <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify" class="h1">
              <h5>By Car</h5> 
             <hr width="100%" align="left" color="#39A2E1"/>
            </div>
            <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify; font-weight:200;" class="p">Felines Termenes is situated half an hour from the A61 (Exit 25, Lezignan), and less then an hour from the E 15 (Exit 39, Sigean).</div>
            <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify; font-weight:200" class="h1"><h5>By Air</h5></div>
            <hr width="100%" align="left" color="#39A2E1"/>
            <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify; font-weight:200" class="p">Budget airlines fly to Carcassonne, Perpignan. Montpellier and Toulouse. The Eurostar goes to Montpellier.  It is possible to hire a car at all airports.</div>
            <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify" class="h1"><h5>By Train</h5></div>
            <hr width="100%" align="left" color="#39A2E1"/>
            <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify; font-weight:200" class="p">The TGV train from Lille and Paris serves Narbonne and Carcassonne. These TGV trains connect with the Eurostar from London.  It is possible to hire a car at all railway stations</div>
    </div>
    <img width="970px" height="600px" style="padding-bottom:20px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Junonia_lemonias_DSF_upper_by_Kadavoor.JPG"/>

       <div class="hrfancy"><hr width="80%" style="position:relative; top:70x"></div>
       <p style="margin: 0px 30px 10px 30px"> The house has been entirely renovated with respect for the original elements like stone walls, wooden beams, … This 5 bedroom house (sleeps 8) is a well equipped property. Situated in one of the most sunny regions of France it profits from a sunny, sheltered court yard and garage in the basement.
         This comfortable property is based in the Languedoc-Roussillon region, famous for its recreational activities as here in Cathar country history meets nature.  From the village you can reach famous historic towns such as Perpignan, Carcassonne and Narbonne within an hour.  Felines is also close to the medieval village of Lagrasse,  one of the “les plus beaux villages de France”. A drive to the sea or Spain equally takes you about an hour.  Take advantage of your stay and visit some vintners, as     Felines-Termenes is on the “Route des 20”, a local initiative of the wine growers of the Corbieres.  With your family or with friends, you will appreciate the calm of this 180 sq.m. property. </p>
    </article>

<footer>Powered By Ruben &copy; 2015 </footer>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.hrfancy { /* taken from http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/ */
    height: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.hrfancy:before { /* taken from http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/ */
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -31px;    
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#contactimg {
    position:relative;
    height:530px;
    width:996px;
}

#contactimg img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 97%;
}

div.scroll {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:rgba(27,27,27,0.60)
}


body {
    margin: 0px;
    color: #151515;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #EFF5F8;
}

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:530px;
    width:996px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}



#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 740px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border:#6627C9;
    background-color:#E2CFAF;
    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-right: 17px;

}

#slideshow img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 97%;
}

#top {
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    color: #3399DD;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 36px;
}

h5 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    color: #3399DD;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

hr{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

#mainimg img {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}


.centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    background-color: #43a6cb;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
}
a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
    color: #FF6600;
}
a:visited {
    color: #FF944C;

}
#mainnav a:hover, #mainnav a:active,#mainnav a:focus , #mainnav a.thispage{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #43A6CB;
}

li:hover hr{
    color: orange;
}

#mainnav ul   {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#mainnav a {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}


#wrapper #main ul.horizontal1 li
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style; none;
}

#wrapper #main .horizontal1 img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#wrapper #main ul.horizontal1 li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style; none;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 25%;
}

ul.horizontal1 {
    list-style; none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20;
    font-size: 0;
}


#wrapper #main ul.horizontall li
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style; none;
}

#wrapper #main ul.horizontall li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style; none;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
}

ul.horizontall {
    list-style; none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

img{
    display: block;
}

*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main {
    padding-left: 10px;
    paddin-right: 10px;
}
```

JAVA: (Just in case)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".popup").hide();

    $(".h1").click(function() {
    $(".h1").next().slideToggle(700);
    });

});
```

I know it has to do with the following positioning, when I did relative position in the .scroll class to position it over the main image, the space where it used to be still existed.

```
<div class="scroll" style="position:relative; left:0px; top:-500px; width:350px; height:480px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px;">
```

Comment: `JAVA: (Just in case)` - where do you see any Java code?

Comment: if you click on some of the headings, the text below dissears

Comment: But it doesnt work because of the fiddle

Comment: can u instead of giving us all the code and basically asking us to go search for the problem ,maybe be more specific and just post the code with the problem.

Comment: Ok let me have a look

Comment: I edited it, I am confident this is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Btw there isn't that much code, it is just the .scroll that maybe needs a different positioning method :L do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started.

Add the image in #contactimg as a background-image:

```
#contactimg {
    position:relative;
    height:530px;
    max-width:100%;
    background-image:url(http://www.personal.psu.edu/cmr5496/sky_main.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

Add the following css to your .scroll (inside your css stylesheet):

```
div.scroll {
    width: 350px;
     height:530px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:rgba(27,27,27,0.60)

}
```

Remove inline styling from your .scroll (inside your html) from:

```
<div class="scroll" style="position:relative; left:0px; top:-500px; width:350px; height:480px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px;">
```

To:

```
   <div class="scroll">...</div>
```

Inside the #contactimg insert the .scroll div:

```
<div id="contactimg">
    <div class="scroll">
        <div style="position:relative; left:65px"><img style="padding-left:px" width="190px" height="180px" src="../Images/Contact Photos/Map5.png"></div>
        <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify" class="h1">
        <h5>By Car</h5> 
        <hr width="100%" align="left" color="#39A2E1"/>
        </div>
        <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify; font-weight:200;" class="p">Felines Termenes is situated half an hour from the A61 (Exit 25, Lezignan), and less then an hour from the E 15 (Exit 39, Sigean).</div>
        <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify; font-weight:200" class="h1"><h5>By Air</h5></div>
        <hr width="100%" align="left" color="#39A2E1"/>
        <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify; font-weight:200" class="p">Budget airlines fly to Carcassonne, Perpignan. Montpellier and Toulouse. The Eurostar goes to Montpellier.  It is possible to hire a car at all airports.</div>
        <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify" class="h1"><h5>By Train</h5></div>
        <hr width="100%" align="left" color="#39A2E1"/>
        <div style="color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); text-align:justify; font-weight:200" class="p">The TGV train from Lille and Paris serves Narbonne and Carcassonne. These TGV trains connect with the Eurostar from London.  It is possible to hire a car at all railway stations</div>
    </div><!-- end scroll -->
    </div><!-- end contactimg -->
```

Remove inline styling from the first div child of .scroll from:

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div style="position:relative; left:65px">...
```

To:

```
<div class="scroll">
        <div>...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fgt7wu8b/